# How do I fix Browserslist in Mongosh

Tags: mongodb, package.json

I get the following output when running mongosh : -

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

I've tried the command, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running Mongo in a Docker container? I am getting the same error. I guess we wait for the maintainer to update the docker image...

Comment: I'm getting this at the first mongosh prompt:
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

Comment: @BenM A bit late to the party but it seems like you chose Roberto's approach to resolving your issue with "browserlist." Nonetheless, what solved the problem for me was to simply update "mongosh" to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run mongosh using this command line:

```
BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA=1 mongosh ...
```

On GNU/Linux or macOSX. Or...

```
set BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA=1
mongosh ...
```

On windows.

This way the message is not shown.

Comment: Meanwhile this bug is fixed in latest mongosh release.